# Drawing an arc between two points

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am trying to draw an arc that connects two circles in Swing. I have to use a shape, so I've tried arcs, quads, and curves, but I can't find one that will simply connect two points with an arc.

Can anyone give me an idea on how to do this? All I have for my code is the two points I need to connect, but their position varies and my arc needs to adjust depending on that.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html - Does this help? Then perhaps you could alter the value of one of the points to distort/change the curve.

Comment: i looked at that already but i have the problem of changing the angles between the circles so arcs wont work. I dont have any control points so the quad and curves wont work. I just want a straight curve given two points

Comment: a sketch of what you want to achieve would be wise to add. for example something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22982623/2521214) so we can see what you mean by connecting 2 circles by arc ....