# Algorithm to convert points to vector lines. (Raster to vector)

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, graphics, raster

How can I convert set of points that (we can assume) create line made of segments (*Top Image*) to vector line (*Bottom image*)?

Is there some algorithm for that? Preferably C++ but even pseudocode will be ok.

[image]

Comment: It think you're interested in edge detection techniques.

Comment: Am I? I think that edge detection will create contour (outline) and not a line.

Comment: To clarify you have access to the exact set of points and their x,y positions?

Comment: Yes. This set of points created through flood fill algorithm. User choose color, tolerance, click on image and the program flood fills some region that is (presumably) a line, of which I want to have vertices.

Comment: use thinning (morphology operators) then sample points and then apply connected components analysys. After that just distinguish lines and curves and fit/join/merge what  you can. see [Approximate a curve with a limited number of line segments and arcs of circles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42998651/2521214)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would approach it:

- Create contour/outline of raster image
- Use these points as a vector contour/outline
- Split the points in half so you have a line that describes the top edge and a line that describes the bottom edge of original outline
- Take the bottom line (or top line) and use a line simplification algorithm (like Reumann-Witkam or Douglas-Peucker) to get a simplified vector line
- Work out how much to offset the line by so it is roughly centered between the original two contour halves.

This should give you reasonable results without much computational complexity.